# Read OBIEE instance config file

Tags: soap, oracle11g, soapui, obiee

In OBIEE, is there any possible web service call to retrieve information saved in instance config file.
I'll explain in detail.
My requirement is to get environment variables like maximum number of rows, http timeout value etc.. which will be saved in instance config file. By using any web service call(SOAP call) can we read those values and use in our application?
In the link given below were the list of web service call that can be made using SOAP UI.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/bi.1111/e16364/methods.htm#BIEIT288

Answer (score 0):

The catalog is the "web catalog" where presentation objects like dashboards, analyses etc are stored.

What you want is something 100% custom and Oracle doesn't provide any APIs for that. So you have to create your own calls.

Comment: Yes, I can understand. But from where do we get the variables like maximum row count, etc..? If we make our own call, we can apply only approximate values say 40000. We need to access instance config file and retrieve the exact information. Can you suggest some option regading this.

Comment: You get it form the files. Oracle did not expose those through APIs for public usage. Do it on your own risk.